# How to send Video File using SOAP/MTOM

Tags: android, soap, android-ksoap2, mtom, xop

I want to upload large size video from my android app, I am using SOAP services to communicate with server, Can any one tell me any way to do this without converting video to `Base64` encoded string and sending it to server in SOAP request as it is very inefficient. And also is there any library available to do this like KSOAP2 for sending SOAP request/response.

After searching a lot I came to know that MTOM is used to send `byte` data to server but how to do it in android is very much unknown.